# write the elements of $S_3$ as product of two permutations with order 2,

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I was trying to write the elements of $S_3$ as product of two permutations with order 2, because I wanted to find a counterexample.

It's not possible for every transposition in $S_3$ right?
For example $(12)=(123)(23)=(23)(13)(23)$. So we can't write this as product of two permutations with order two because they aren't disjunct.

I was wondering if this was true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every element/permutation in $S_3$, there is a property called the *sign* that is associated with it.

A  transposition is an element of order two. The sign of a permutation, is the parity of the number of transpositions which it is the product of, regardless of how many transpositions there are in that product. Indeed, you can show that this parity remains unchanged even under a different representation via a product of permutations. For example, $(12) = (23)(13)(23)$ but the parity of both sides is odd.

The parity of a transposition is *odd*, which means that it cannot be written therefore, as the product of two transpositions.

However, the proof that $(12)$ cannot be written as the product of two permutations can be made clearer. Suppose that $(12) = (ab)(cd)$. Then, we know that one of $a,b,c,d$ is a $2$, and one of them is a $1$. $2$ and $1$ cannot appear in the same bracket, since that would give $(12)$, which would cancel out from both sides and give that the identity is a transposition, a contradiction.

So, WLOG, $(12) = (1b)(c2)$. Then, it must happen that $b=c$, since $2$ goes to $1$, and if $b \neq c$ this won;t happen. But then $b = c \neq 1,2$ gives a contradiction, as $1$ goes to $b$ above.

Hence, $(12)$ cannot be written as the product of two transpositions.